# Не удается увеличить максимальное число резидентов

Tags: c#, unity3d

первый раз делаю игру на unity и C#, на данный момент, проблема в том, что я не знаю, как с использованием триггера увеличить максимальное число резидентов. \

Как это должно работать: Есть дом, который увеличивает максимальное число резидентов на 6, к нему я пристраиваю вышку, которая должна увеличить то же число, но уже на 3.

Для этого всего я использую Box Collider, в котором выставлены галочки на Is trigger, Rigibody я так же поставил. Когда я строю вышку, то число не возрастает,

вот код:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class House : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int resident;

    public int maxResident;

    public int residentAdd;

    float residentTime;

    public int energy;

    public int energyUse;

    float energyTime;

    public int residentDied;

    float DiedTime;

    public int tax;

    public int taxAdd;

    float taxTime;


    `GameObject resources;

    void Start()
    {
        resources = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("resourcesController");
        resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().maxResident += maxResident;
        resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().building += 1;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (resident < 0)
        {
            resident = 0;
        }
        ResidentAdd();
        Energy();
        Tax();
        Died();
    }


    void ResidentAdd()
    {
        residentTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (residentTime >= residentAdd)
        {
            if (resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident < resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().maxResident)
            {
                if (resident < maxResident)
                {
                    resident += 1;
                    resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident += 1;
                }
            }
            residentTime = 0;
        }

    }
    
    void Energy()
    {
        int allEnergy;
        energyTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if(energyTime >= energyUse)
        {
            allEnergy = resident * energy;
            if(allEnergy <= resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy)
            {
                resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy -= allEnergy;
            } else
            {
                while(allEnergy > resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy)
                {
                    resident -= 1;
                    resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident -= 1;
                    allEnergy -= 1;
                }
            }
            allEnergy = 0;
            energyTime = 0;
        }
    }

    void Tax()
    {
        int allTax;
        taxTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (taxTime >= taxAdd)
        {
            allTax = resident * tax;
            resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().gold += allTax;
            allTax = 0;
            taxTime = 0;
        }
    }

    void Died()
    {
        DiedTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (DiedTime >= residentDied)
        {
            resident -= 1;
            resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident -= 1;
            DiedTime = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Tower")
        {
            maxResident += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// если не используются, их не должно быть
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class House : MonoBehaviour
{
    // публичных полей не должно быть
    // тут 3 разные отвественности resident, energy и tax которые должны быть выделины в 3 разных класс
    public int resident;
    public int maxResident;
    public int residentAdd;
    float residentTime;
    public int energy;
    public int energyUse;
    float energyTime;
    public int residentDied;
    float DiedTime;
    public int tax;
    public int taxAdd;
    float taxTime;

    // почему GameObject? сразу ResourcesController нельзя?
    GameObject resources;

    void Start ()
    {
        // FindGameObject вообще пользоваться, категорически неправильно
        // FindGameObjectWithTag тем более, строковые литералы пораждают ошибки
        // Классы более низкого уровня не должны знать о существовании класса более высокого, а ResourcesController выше House
        resources = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("resourcesController");
        // GetComponent это операция затрачивающая ресурсы
        // ResourcesController дублирует значения, этого не болжно быть, как и самого ResourcesController в House
        resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().maxResident += maxResident;
        resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().building += 1;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // условие явно лечит неподконтрольное изменение значения, костыли
        if (resident < 0)
        {
            resident = 0;
        }
        // хорошо что ты поделил 4 процесса на 4 метода, но названия не отображает что в них
        ResidentAdd(); // UpdateGeneration (в раммках класса Residents)
        Energy(); 
        Tax();
        Died(); // UpdateDisappearance (в раммках класса Residents)
    }

    void ResidentAdd ()
    {
        // 1*Time.deltaTime = Time.deltaTime
        residentTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (residentTime >= residentAdd)
        {
            // если ResourcesController дублирует суммарное количество значений в домах то эта проверка не имеет смысла
            if (resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident < resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().maxResident)
            {
                if (resident < maxResident)
                {
                    resident += 1;
                    resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident += 1;
                }
            }
            // а куда девается остаток?
            residentTime = 0;
        }
    }

    void Energy ()
    {
        int allEnergy;
        energyTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (energyTime >= energyUse)
        {
            // смысл объявлять allEnergy ранее?
            // все энергия = житель * энергия... бросай наркотики
            // видимо речь про потребление энергии, тогда так и нужно называть energyСonsumption
            // или скорее назвать energyRequired, а сам метод UpdateСonsumption (в раммках класса Energy), тогда все начнет иметь смысл
            allEnergy = resident * energy;
            if (allEnergy <= resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy)
            {
                resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy -= allEnergy;
            }
            else
            {
                while (allEnergy > resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().energy)
                {
                    resident -= 1;
                    resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident -= 1;
                    allEnergy -= 1;
                }
            }
            // не там обьявил и теперь нужны костыли
            allEnergy = 0;
            energyTime = 0;
        }
    }

    void Tax ()
    {
        int allTax;
        taxTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (taxTime >= taxAdd)
        {
            // сново здарово
            // all переводится как "все", но речь все таки штуках, а о суммарном/общем налоге totalTax
            allTax = resident * tax;
            // весь метод именно ради этого и посвещен он вовсе не налогу, то-есть вычитании денег, а получении дохода, то-есть UpdateIncome
            resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().gold += allTax;
            // сново здарово
            allTax = 0;
            taxTime = 0;
        }
    }

    void Died ()
    {
        // сново здарово
        DiedTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (DiedTime >= residentDied)
        {
            resident -= 1;
            resources.GetComponent<ResourcesController>().resident -= 1;
            DiedTime = 0;
        }
    }

    // ни разу не писал private и тут на... вообще-то везде должны быть включая поля, ну или нигде, чисто ради консистенции, чтоб не шеш беш
    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        // опять строковый литерал, работа с ними не безопасна, нужно проверять на компонент или интерфейс
        // если House или Tower могут столкнуться, значит кто-то из них или оба двигаются... бросай наркотики
        if (other.tag == "Tower")
        {
            // это что? Tower трахнул House толи в дымоход толи в парадную и... бросай тяжелые наркотики
            maxResident += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

`ResourcesController` какой-то монструозный класс, там буквально все, включая такой ресурс как `maxResident` .
Такого класса вообще не должно быть. Инфа по домам отдельно, валюта отдельно

```
public class HouseManager
{
    private List<House> _houses;

    // добавляет некий HouseSpanwer
    public void AddHouse (House house)
    {
        _houses.Add(house);
    }

    public int GetResidentsCount ()
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (House house in _houses)
            count += house.Residents.CurrentCount;
        return count;
    }

    public int GetResidentsCapacity ()
    ...
}
```

Валюта к сцене не привязана, для нее лучше использовать `singleton`

```
[Serializable]
public struct CurrencyAmount
{
    public int gold;
    public int diamonds;
}

public enum CurrencyType { Gold, Diamonds }

public class Currency
{
    private const string Key = "Currency";
    private static Currency _instance;

    public Action<CurrencyType, int> Changed;
    private CurrencyAmount _amount;

    private Currency ()
    {
        Load();
    }

    public static Currency Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Currency();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public int Gold
    {
        get => GetAmount(CurrencyType.Gold);
        set => SetAmount(CurrencyType.Gold, value);
    }

    public int Diamonds
    {
        get => GetAmount(CurrencyType.Diamonds);
        set => SetAmount(CurrencyType.Diamonds, value);
    }

    public int GetAmount (CurrencyType currency)
    {
        switch (currency)
        {
            case CurrencyType.Gold: return _amount.gold;
            case CurrencyType.Diamonds: return _amount.diamonds;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    public void SetAmount (CurrencyType currency, int amount)
    {
        switch (currency)
        {
            case CurrencyType.Gold: _amount.gold = amount; break;
            case CurrencyType.Diamonds: _amount.diamonds = amount; break;
        }
        Changed?.Invoke(currency, amount);
        Save();
    }

    private void Load ()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(Key))
        {
            string json = PlayerPrefs.GetString(Key);
            _amount = JsonUtility.FromJson<CurrencyAmount>(json);
        }
    }

    private void Save ()
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_amount);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(Key, json);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```